# Values in the querystring does not bind the params in the action .NET Core 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using .NET Core 5 with C#. I sometimes get an error for a null parameter called `lang`; but I don't see problems in the url, and when I get to the action I can see these values in the `HttpContext`:

```
QueryString = '?lang=es&BrandURLName=hp'
Querykeys = 'lang,BrandURLName'
QueryValues = '[lang, en],[BrandURLName, hp]'
```

This is the action body:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> category_onfilterchange(string lang, string sectionurlname, string categoryurlname, vmCategory model)
{
    // code       
}
```

This is the Ajax call:

```
var obj = $("#form-main").serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    url: "/category/category_onfilterchange?lang=@Model.cmCurrentLanguageISOCode&sectionurlname=@Model.SectionURLName&categoryurlname=@Model.CategoryURLName",
    data: obj,
    success: function (response) {
    },
    error: function (jqxhr, status, error) {
    }
});
```

For some reason, the param `lang` cannot be bound, but this just happen sometimes

Comment: did you try using `[FromQuery]` on your parameters?

Comment: You can put a breakpoint to url property in ajax call and debug. Check whether model properties have values there. Seems like you have complete string without model values.

Comment: Can you share the url in ajax when the lang is null?It looks like the lang of value is es,and I test with `?lang=es&BrandURLName=hp`,`lang` will be es in action `category_onfilterchange`.

Comment: @DanielA.White yes I did but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Framework don't know how to map those values down to your action. Looking at your code there are two different data sources where you put your values.

- Query string `url: "/category/category_onfilterchange?lang=@Model.cmCurrentLanguageISOCode&sectionurlname=@Model.SectionURLName&categoryurlname=@Model.CategoryURLName",`
- Body `data: obj,`

In which you assumed the framework will magically map it to your action parameters. Unfortunately, it won't map. There are [action level attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0) you can use to instruct framework how to map these values.

[image: Action Attributes]

However, I'm not sure if you can combine `[FromQuery]` and `[FromBody]` in one action without creating [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0). I personally haven't tried it before so please read the link and proceed at your discretion.

My recommendation is to create one object to combine properties of `obj`, `lang`, `sectionurlname`, and `categoryurlname`. Pass it as `data: CombinedObjectHere` and remove query string because you no longer need it. Then change your action into this `category_onfilterchange([FromBody]CombinedObjectHere model)`. Obviously, you need to create POCO class of `CombinedObjectHere`.